# Set Grid Column width between 2 enums in Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am building a ui using Semantic UI React library and want to set a column width between 3 and 4. I am using 3.5 and 0.5 but since the library enums do not support it, the design is not rendering properly. All the column widths add up to 16.

This is how the UI is rendering
[image]

This is how I want it to be. Mobile width: 3.5, spacer: 0.5, text: 3, spacer: 1 and so on
[image]

```
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={1} />
          <Grid.Column width={3.5}>
            <Image src={mobileQuizPrevious} />
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={0.5} />
          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>
              <strong>Before</strong>
              <br />
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
              augue nulla, condimentum a tortor non, gestas maximus neque.
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={1} />
          <Grid.Column width={3.5}>
            <Image src={mobileQuizNew} />
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={0.5} />
          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>
              <strong>After</strong>
              <br />
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
              augue nulla, condimentum a tortor non, gestas maximus neque.
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
```

Semantic UI grid width options

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. Came quite close to the intended design

```
<Grid.Row centered>
          <Grid.Column width={1} />
          <Grid.Column width={3} style={{ marginRight: "1em" }}>
            <Image src={image1} />
          </Grid.Column>

          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>
              <strong>Before</strong>
              <br />
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
              augue nulla, condimentum a tortor non, gestas maximus neque.
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={1} />
          <Grid.Column width={3} style={{ marginRight: "1em" }}>
            <Image src={image2} />
          </Grid.Column>

          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>
              <strong>After</strong>
              <br />
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
              augue nulla, condimentum a tortor non, gestas maximus neque.
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
```